aws s3 curl PUT works but fetch in JavaScript does not
This question has been asked a number of times, but the answer has always been "Include the Content-Type in the header". I have done this many times with different values to no avail.
I'm trying to upload an image.
Here is my code:
const res = await fetch(preSignedUrl, {
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': mimetype,
        },
        body: file
      });

The presigned url comes from my backend:
static async createPreSignedUrl(key: string | undefined, mimetype: string | undefined): Promise<string> {
    if (!key || !mimetype) {
      throw new Error(`Cannot create a pre-signed url without a key or a mimetype`);
    }
    const client = new S3Client({
      credentials: {
        accessKeyId: String(process.env.AWS_S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID),
        secretAccessKey: String(process.env.AWS_S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY),
      },
      region: String(process.env.AWS_S3_REGION),
    });
    const command = new PutObjectCommand({
      Bucket: String(process.env.AWS_S3_ASSETS_BUCKET_NAME),
      Key: key,
      ContentType: mimetype
    });
    return getSignedUrl(client, command, {
      expiresIn: 3600
    });
  }

I don't believe the pre-signed url is the issue since using curl in CMD works correctly:
>curl -X PUT -H 'Content-Type:image/jpeg' -T "71k4prNp07S._UF1000,1000_QL80_.jpg" -L "pre-signed-url-here"
I'm really hoping that someone can help.

Turns out that CORS was not setup on the AWS server and that's what was causing issues. Allowing my domains through CORS resolved the issue.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
